# Bootstrap floating elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I've got a view with Angular (v.5) components, that uses Bootstrap for making the layout in the screen. So I've got various controls, one at the left, which uses most of the space (col-md-8), and two controls which are inline, in the right part (col-md-4).

Even trying col-sm I notice that in little displays (less than 1280px), the two components in the right, get overlapped one over the other. Check:

[image: This is how it looks in big screens, the intended behavior]

This is how it looks in big screens, the intended behavior

[image: But one of them "mounts" over the other like this, when you make the window a little smaller]

But one of them "mounts" over the other like this, when you make the window a little smaller

[image: It even reaches this point...]

It even reaches this point...

[image: But when you make the window really really small, it looks like this, which is *fine* in my opinion.]

But when you make the window really really small, it looks like this, which is *fine* in my opinion.

I want to do that one of these components, actually just puts in top or bottom side of the other, or simple get advantage of all the free space, instead of getting overlapped by the other like it currently does.

This is the current code of this header of my template, give it a look:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
       <segments [config]="config"></segments>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4  date-positioning"> 
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <granularity [config]="config" ></granularity>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8"> 
           <date-picker-wrapper [config]="config"  [dateranges]="dateranges" [doubleDateRange]="true" ></date-picker-wrapper>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What you see are the granularity and daterangepicker components, the segments one is the component you see in the final image, which occupies most of the left side of the screen (but there's a reason for that)

So, any ideas on how to style this properly with Bootstrap, so this weird behavior doesn't happen?

Comment: from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ "Columns have horizontal padding to create the gutters between individual columns, however, you can remove the margin from rows and padding from columns with **.no-gutters** on the .row."

Comment: @Eliseo if I do that, the elements always appear overlapped, so it doesn't seem to fix it that much.